# ValidationGroup Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a text box with required field validator:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Pleas Enter Name" ControlToValidate="txtCName"  ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I need to show error message on button click:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
                        ValidationGroup="sub">
```

I am using the following code to assign validation group to the required field validator (it is in `document.ready()` function) :-

```
$("#<%=rfvCName.ClientID %>").attr('ValidationGroup', 'sub');
```

But it is not showing any error message on button click. Please help me.
I need to do it using Jquery. I don't want to assign ValidatioGroup directly to the control.

Comment: Add ValidationGroup="Sub" in

Comment: try in chrome with developper tools to verify that validationgroup is added

Comment: Yes it is coming :-     <span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_rfvCName" style="color:Red;visibility:hidden;" validationgroup="sub">Pleas Enter Name</span>

Answer (score 0):

Add validation group ValidationGroup="Sub"

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Pleas Enter Name" ValidationGroup="sub" ControlToValidate="txtCName"  ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

when the page(server side) prerender the object requiredFieldValidator, some javascript is added into page automatically by .net framework.

this javascrript code check the validationgroup.

add manually the validationgroup attribute client-side without this javascript code not work.
you can see this code in developpers tool searching "ValidationGroup"

if you cannot add attribute in html, you can add this attribute in a event server side like load or prerender.